# Import from ipython

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

If I use IDLE with python 2.7

```
import cv
import cv2
```

and it works

but if I use ipython notebook

it gives me error

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>    last)  in ()
>    ----> 1 import cv
>
> ImportError: No module named cv

So how to use OpenCV from iPython?

**EDIT:**

from IDLE

> ['', 'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg',
>   'C:\WINDOWS\system32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\DLLs',
>   'C:\Python27\lib', 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Python27',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL']

from ipython anaconda

> ['', 'C:\Anaconda\python27.zip', 'C:\Anaconda\DLLs',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib', 'C:\Anaconda\lib\plat-win',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Anaconda',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PIL',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
>   'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions']

so the questions seems to be how to install opencv in ipython anaconda? (and why it doesn't use standard python packages)

Comment: Anaconda has a separate Python installation, so it won't find libraries installed in your `C:\Python27\` installation. It should be possible to install libraries in either installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is your PYTHONPATH different in ipython and IDLE?
try the following

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

I suspect the two won't match. have you launched IDLE and ipython from the same terminal?

Comment: I check them, see edit. Also I run IDLE from menu shortcut and ipython in cmd by command "ipython notebook".

Comment: looks like anaconda is overriding your PYTHONPATH. Quick fix is simply to append your standard PYTHONPATH to your anaconda one before you try to import opencv. Eg:  sys.path += ['', 'C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim-0.8.6-py2.7.egg', 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\python27.zip', 'C:\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\Python27\lib', 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\Python27', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL']